# How to assert that a dynamic image is not present in a webpage in Selenium Python web driver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is webpage that loads 4 images dynamically. They cannot be clicked and in the source code there is only `src` attribute. Using XPath I found the URL for each image. How do I find if a particular image is present or not on page load? I need this in Selenium Python web driver.

Below is the code which I need to automate:

```html
<div class="row">
<div id="1" class="xx">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yy"> <img src="/img/images/pic-1.jpg"> </div>
        <div class="a"> hello 1 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yy"> <img src="/img/images/pic-2.jpg"> </div>
        <div class="a"> Hello 2 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yy"> <img src="/img/images/pic-3.jpg"> </div>
        <div class="a"> Hello 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The image keeps changing every time the page is loaded. I need to find if `pic-1.jpg` is present/displayed when the page is loaded.

Comment: "How do i find a particular image is present or not on page load."  Please elaborate. For example - what do you mean by 'find' ?

Comment: It basically a site, which has 4 images (like profile pic - image 1, image 2 , image 3, image 4) and corresponding content beside it. Each time i access the site, I need to find say an Image 3 which may or may not be present, since the images keep changing rather getting replaced with another image for every refresh.

Comment: Did you try my below code. use as similier in python

Comment: Can you provide a link and description of an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "its present on the page"? Do you mean image tag is present? Or image is shown on the page?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML? Are you talking about 1 of 4 images being present or up to 4 images being present and wanting to return which ones are missing or ???

Comment: <div class="row">
<div id="1" class="xx">
<div class="row">
<div class="yy">
<img src="/img/images/pic-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="a"> hello 1 </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="yy">
<img src="/img/images/pic-2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="a"> Hello 2 </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="yy">
<img src="/img/images/pic-3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="a"> Hello 3 </div>
</div>    HTML code looks like this. Here the image keeps changing everytime the page is loaded. I need to find if pic-1.jpg is present/displayed when the page is loaded.

Comment: If the images change and the names changes too (each time a different image will be called "pic-1.jpg"), you will need save the pic-1.jpg image  (not using selenium in this case) and compare it with a source image in your desktop if they are the same or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but since you don't have any other answers I'll try to help you with some Java code that hopefully you can translate.

You basically want to grab all the `IMG` tags inside a `DIV` with class `yy`. You then loop through that collection of elements looking for the desired picture name in the `src` string. If it is found, the element HTML is printed.

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.yy > img"));
String imageFileName = "pic-1.jpg";
for (WebElement image : images)
{
    if (image.getAttribute("src").contains(imageFileName))
    {
        System.out.println(image.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeffC-> OP is asking for python code while you are giving him java code. This way you may confuse OP and it's against this forum rules

Comment: Can you point me to the "forum rules" that state that I can't provide an answer in another language? This question is 4 days old and is likely never going to receive an answer. Someone with basic python knowledge should be able to read this code and translate it. I could spend probably 15 minutes and figure out how to do it in python but I'd rather do something else with my time. I can understand not picking this as the answer if there is another but I don't understand why people are downvoting this answer when it's perfectly valid for at least learning the concepts involved in the answer.

Comment: I have not gone through rules book, but people are downvoting me in many places because of same reason

Comment: ...just because others do it doesn't mean it's right or even a good idea. I looked and I don't see any rules against providing an answer in another language. Downvoting means that the answer is not useful and I disagree with that. I understand it's not optimal but I'd rather have an answer in another language that I can learn concepts from and translate than no answer or a bad answer... I guess that's just me.